# in discord.py How can i make my bot that the commands only can be use in specific channel or specific server?

Tags: javascript, python, discord

So, anyone can invite my personal bot to their server. So, I want the command will work on specific channel or specific server with @bot.event not client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `await bot.process_commands(message)` you can try this

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == yourchannelid:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
    
    if message.guild.id = yourguildid:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

you can add checks in on_message so the bot doesn't reply to itself